# Evil Twins? Modes vs Mirrors

Tags: theory, scales, modes

I noticed that  the algorithm for Phyrgian mode is the mirror image of that for Ionian: 
(Numbers indicate count of chromatic tones - 'semitones')

**Ionian:**

> ***Root->2-2-1-2-2-2-1:Root***

**Phyrgian:**

> ***Root->1-2-2-2-1-2-2:Root***

`2212221` -  Ionian, rendered backwards is `1222122` - Phyrgian.

I cannot be the first one to have noticed this.

***Edit: @ToddWilcox has pointed out in the comments that it's not just Ionian vs Phyrgian, but starting from Dorian, going one mode away on either side finds a backwards pairing.***

Are there practical implications and applications of this bit of theoretical trivia, or is all this just a mathematical curiosity?

---

***How can we use these relationships to help us make better, more interesting music, be it in terms of composition or improvisation?***

Comment: Isn't backwards Locrian the same as Lydian? And Dorian backwards is Dorian? And Mixolydian and Aeolian are each other backwards? And that's all seven. Actually starting from Dorian, going one mode away on either side finds a backwards pairing. Then two modes away finds the second pair, and three modes finds the third.

Comment: Also the backwards partner of each major mode is a minor mode. Aside from Dorian, the backwards partner of each minor mode is a major mode.

Comment: @ToddWilcox -  Maybe that all makes the question more interesting - it's not just Phyrgian vs Ionian.   I need the **math** here...

Comment: Personally I find the math boring and I'm curious as to whether the "mathematical" relationship has a corresponding musical relationship. Of course one could use this curious fact as compositional inspiration but is that all (as you are asking)?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - the math helps you to generalize and develop rules (I'm a programmer by trade so I like that sort of thing...) But yes, my question here is strictly musical - how can we use these relationships to help us make better, more interesting music, be it in terms of composition or improvisation.

Comment: I liked the original title haha

Comment: @Some_Guy - Fixed it for you. Now answer the question. :)

Comment: The way that the major and minor modes are constructed (by piling fifths on top of each other and normalizing to one octave) makes this inevitable. And since the most common modes can all be defined as reframings of the tones in the major scale, the same goes for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I noticed alright.
[image: Modes decoded]

Remembering 4152637 will help all your modulating needs, whether composing or improvising. The circle of fifths comes to the rescue once again! I suppose you could call it a mirror modulation.

Comment: Good chart... Mistake in the first line - C/Gb:4 Should be C/F.

Comment: That's the Lydian mode, so the 4 is sharp. I labelled it as Gb to keep it consistent with the other black keys, though really it's F#.

Comment: OK - I think it should be spelled correctly though.

Comment: Then what would I do about the Gb on Locrian? Either way one is technically wrong.

Comment: Understood - in your chart you can only use Gb because you used only b's - that makes sense because (never really thought about this until now ) it seems that when C is the root,  Lydian is the only mode that needs a #.